# Getting VoraConfigurationException: Following parameter(s) are invalid: serialization.format (state=,code=0)

Tags: vora

I am getting this error when using Thrift server and beeline client (also seeing it with zeppelin):

> 0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:12000> show tables; Error:
>   org.spark-project.guava.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
>   com.sap.spark.vora.VoraConfigurationException: Following parameter(s)
>   are invalid: serialization.format (state=,code=0)

I am using Vora 1.1 patch 1 and Spark 1.5.2. The vora extension jar is 1.2.0 (spark-sap-datasources-1.2.10-assembly.jar).
Any idea what is wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the port number, is it by default not 49155?

Comment: Not really. I started the Thrift server at 12000 and in fact, could connect it to successfully as the beeline prompt shows. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Which Spark are you using? I have seen a similar problem when using the Spark 1.5.2 coming with HDP2.3.4. Surprisingly the Hortonworks' Spark1.5.2 is a bit different from Apache Spark 1.5.2. Vora 1.1 Patch 1 is not completely compatible with the HDP2.3.4-Spark version. With Vora1.2 this issue has been resolved and it is compatible with Hortonworks' version.
Assuming you use HDP2.3.4's Spark version there are 2 options: (1) Upgrade Vora to 1.2 or (2) uninstall HDP's Spark version and manually install a Apache Spark 1.5.2 outside of Ambari.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I am using Apache Spark 1.5.2 and not the Spark that comes with the HDP distribution. Here I am using HDP 2.3.0 on RHEL 7.1as that is the supported distro on RHEL 7.1.

Comment: BTW, I ran into some other issues with Vora 1.0/RHEL 6/HDP 2.3.2/Spark 1.4.1.